# Does $x^n$ belong to $O(e^x)$ for all $n\geq 1$?

Tags: calculus, functions

My question is essentially two-fold. I've been asked to prove that $x^5 \in$ $O(e^x)$ as $x\to \infty$, and trying to do that I decided to plot some functions of the form $x^n$ next to $e^x$, and noted that after some (possibly very large) point $e^x$ tends to outgrow $x^n$. Now, I only tested this up to about $n=7$ as the numbers get extremely large, but I wonder if the pattern holds up for all $n$?

I tried thinking about this inductively, i.e. supposing that $x^n\in$ $O(e^x)$ up to some $n$, then for $x^{n+1}$ we have that its rate of growth is $(n+1)x^n$, which is in $O(e^x)$ by the inductive hypothesis, hence $e^x$ must outgrow $x^{n+1}$ eventually.I am not sure, however, if that is correct. Either way, I lack the intuition as to why that happens (if it does), so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Just look at the Taylor expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: It is well-known that $x^n\in o(\mathrm e^x)$ for all $n$, hence it is in $O(\mathrm e^x)$.

Comment: Simply using induction here is little dangerous: we know that $x \in O(x^2)$ and $x^2 \in O(x^2)$, but $x^3 = x \cdot x^2 \notin O(x^2)$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$, which is a sum of positive terms for $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to mentioned Taylor expansion you can prove limit
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x} = 0$$
simply using L'Hôpital's rule appropriate number times.